# Make AJAX loaded content crawlable by Google

Tags: jquery, seo, search-engine, html

I build many one page websites that dynamically load content through AJAX/jQuery. I keep reading how bad one pagers are for SEO. Regardless, how can you get the most SEO results out of a one page website, without splitting it up into multiple pages?

Comment: My suggestion is, generating sitemap.xml programatically that contains your pages(for example with item detail pages). For example,

Comment: Take a look to [this article](http://moz.com/blog/how-to-allow-google-to-crawl-ajax-content) too.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: Is there a better stack for asking SEO questions? Did I overlooked the SEO stack??

Comment: @JohnConde Arguably it's a question about programming for SEO benefit. However it may be worth posting to webmasters.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I'll post SEO questions on the webmaster stack from now on.

Comment: To those voting to close: how is dynamically loading content through AJAX/jQuery not about programming? If it had been a question about optimising wording for SEO benefit then fair enough, but come on...

Comment: I do agree, it is about programming SEO friendly. Probably the title question should have been more like: "How to make AJAX loaded content crawlable for Google?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/)

> If you're running an AJAX application with content that you'd like to
>   appear in search results, we have a new process that, when
>   implemented, can help Google (and potentially other search engines)
>   crawl and index your content. Historically, AJAX applications have
>   been difficult for search engines to process because AJAX content is
>   produced dynamically by the browser and thus not visible to crawlers.
>   While there are existing methods for dealing with this problem, they
>   involve regular manual maintenance to keep the content up-to-date.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed. Google can read one pagers if you apply proper #! linking.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using hash(#) for one page navigation an continuing my explanation.
My suggestion is, generating sitemap.xml programatically that contains your pages(for example with item detail pages). Let me show you example,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
   <url>
      <loc><![CDATA[http://your_domain.com/#item-1.html]]></loc>
   </url>
   <url>
      <loc><![CDATA[http://your_domain.com/#item-2.html]]></loc>
   </url>
</urlset>
```

You can put your items' urls in sitemap and submit to google through web master tools.

However, multiple page structure is better than one page for SEO